# How to filter IP address in a hotspot/tether

Tags: wifi-hotspot, firewall, filter

For non rooted phone IP can be filtered/blocked by using a firewall like *NoRoot firewall*. Every apps in the pthone can be controlled this way. But when mobile data is shared with other devices (like tether to a PC, WiFi hotspot) they aren't under the control of the firewall. Applications, like software update, on the other devices are sucking the whole data which lead to exhaustion of mobile data.

So How to filter IP/domain from  connection on a phone that act as a WiFi/USB hotspot.
I have visited many *hotspot manager* apps but none of them seems to have a filter option. Does any hotspot manager support it? or any method? nonroot highly recommended.

**Update  **

PLAN to identify spam IPs
After creating the hotspot client devices are connected. Clients are requested wait for some time so that spam apps begin to update/download by connecting to their server. These IPs are noted and filtered by the hotspot manager.

Comment: I believe your question is this: In your device you can control which app gets to connect to Internet and fetch or send data by using the said firewall app. However, when your phone is tethered the other connected devices consume like hell because the apps on those devices are not controlled by anything, so they all try to get a share of mobile data through hotspot.

Comment: But why are you trying to filter the whole IP address? Filtering usually implies restricting something and that would mean access denied to the whole device. Is that what you want? Or the objective is to identify and restrict a particular request from an app running on an other device? In Android 4.2.1 you can block the tethered device's IP address temporarily. Which Android version and device do you have?

Comment: ICS. stock ROM. I don't want to block the client. Just some domains from that client like *updaes.android.com*

Comment: That can be achieved through DNS. On rooted device put `0.0.0.0 updaes.android.com` in `/etc/hosts`. On non-rooted devices use some firewall or ads-blocking VPN app that incorporates `hosts` functionality.